# Count words in multiple files and show the count and in how many files it appeared

Tags: python

I have a path with 500 files and i need to count the words in all of them to show the word count and in how many files that word was found, i tried to use dict() and a variable for counting the files but only managed to count the words:

```
counts = dict()
...
for filename in fileList:
   file=open(filename, 'r')
   for line in file:
      words += line.split()
   for word in words:
      if word in counts:
         counts[word] += 1
      else:
         counts[word] = 1   
...
for item in counts.items():
    writer=open("Output.txt","a", encoding="utf8")
    writer.write("{}".format(item)+"\n")
    writer.close()
```

I'm a python newbie, the expected output is a file like this:

[image: like this]

**(** word **;** count of that word **;** # of files where that word appeared **)**

Comment: You can apply [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and feed every file into it, after that use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) with custom divider to write results in desired format.

Comment: You haven't shows us how you are looping through the files.  You will probably need a separate counter dict for that.

Comment: Done! i added the code, the loop and the count of words works but the file count does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but this shows the theory:

```
from collections import Counter

files = Counter()
words = Counter()

for fn in list_of_files:
    thisfile = set()
    for word in open(fn).read().split():
        words[word] += 1
        thisfile.add( word )
    for word in thisfile:
        files[word] += 1

writer = open("Output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
for word in files.keys():
    print( f"{word};{words[word]};{files[word]}", file=writer)
```

Comment: I got an AttributeError in the cycle with open(fn).split() because an '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split', i solved it by creating an array words1[], looping "for line in file: words1+= line.split" and using "for word in words1" instead of for "word in  open(fn).split():

Comment: Yes, it should have been `open(fn).read().split()`.  There is no need to read by lines here.  All you want is words.